# Push Twilio alerts to Slack Channel directly

Tags: twilio, slack, twilio-api

I am not sure that there is way but can I send Twilio alerts from Twilio Console to Slack channel directly without using Python or any web framework that will listen to Twilio requests and send the data to Slack channel?

Using Twilio console, I can trigger a webhook from there once there is a new error but the Slack requires a data in the API.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks as though Slack expects webhooks to be in JSON format in a particular format, in the simplest form an object with a `text` property.

Twilio webhooks are sent in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format with [the parameters listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/troubleshooting/alert-triggers#request-parameters).

In order to turn this into a webhook that Slack will understand you will need some code or service that will translate the form encoded request into a JSON request with the right fields.

It seems you are reticent to build and host something yourself. If the hosting is the problem, can I suggest you look into [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) to build this. Twilio Functions lets you host JavaScript functions that can respond to incoming HTTP requests.

An example of a Twilio Function that could translate these alert webhooks into a Slack webhook might look like this:

```js
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const slackUrl = context.SLACK_URL;
  const { ErrorCode, Description, AccountSid } = event;

  const message = `New error for Twilio Account ${AccountSid}.\n\n${ErrorCode}: ${Description}`

  try {
    await got(slackUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ text: message })
    })
    callback(null, "<Response/>");
  } catch(error) {
    callback(error);
  }
}
```

The above code is untested, but should give you a good a start. It uses [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) to make the HTTP request to the Slack webhook URL. In this case, the webhook URL is stored in an [environment variable](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/variables).

Comment: You’re welcome! If it helped, be sure to mark it as correct so that others can see that it was useful too. Thanks!

Comment: ```{
    "message": "require() of ES Module /var/task/node_modules/got/dist/source/index.js from /var/task/handlers/ZN271ef7bdbc31a1a2a612c92200643b54.js not supported.\nInstead change the require of index.js in /var/task/handlers/ZN271ef7bdbc31a1a2a612c92200643b54.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.",
supported.\nInstead change the require of index.js in /var/task/handlers/ZN271ef7bdbc31a1a2a612c92200643b54.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.\n    at Module.twilioRequire ...}
```

Comment: @Vlad The answer is in the error message. You are trying to `require` a module that only supports `import`. You need to use a dynamic import (`await import(“modulename”)`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like twilio changed something, here is slightly updated @philnash code which works fine for me:

```js
exports.handler = async function (context, event, callback) {
  const slackUrl =  context.SLACK_URL;
  const { ErrorCode, Description, AccountSid } = event

  const message = `New error for Twilio Account ${AccountSid}.\n\n${ErrorCode}: ${Description}`

  try {
    const { default: got } = await import('got')

    await got(slackUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ text: message })
    })
    callback(null, '<Response/>')
  } catch (error) {
    callback(error)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one should work in Python 3.8, where body actually arrives as encodedBase64:

````py
def decode_base64(encoded_str):
    try:
        decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(encoded_str)
        decoded_str = decoded_bytes.decode('utf-8')
        return decoded_str
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error decoding base64: {str(e)}")
        return None


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    slack_webhook = os.environ.get('SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL')
    try:
        decoded_body = decode_base64(event['body'])
        qp = parse_qs(decoded_body)
        body = {"Description": qp.get('Description', [None])[0]}
        slack_payload = {"text": "*Twilio Alert* ```{}```".format(json.dumps(body, indent=2))}
        response = requests.post(url=slack_webhook, data=json.dumps(slack_payload))
        return {
                'statusCode': 200,
                'body': json.dumps({"message": 'Webhook sent to Slack successfully'})
                }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps({'Error': str(e)})
        }
````