# Push Twilio SMS programmable messaging logs with status of Undelivered to Slack channel

Tags: json, twilio, webhooks, slack, twilio-api

We are currently caught in the predicament where we are waiting for our Twilio A2P 10DLC campaign to be registered and our outgoing SMS's are being undelivered because of this. The registration process can take up to 3 weeks.

We want to be able to monitor any failed outgoing SMS's from Twilio with the status of `Undelivered` which can be found in the below dashboard:

https://console.twilio.com/us1/monitor/logs/sms

Instead of us manually refreshing this console to see if any SMS's were undelivered, we would like to send these logs to a Slack channel by using a JSON webhook if possible.

There is another thread on here talking about using functions and Slack to transform the alert to JSON format so it can be sent to Slack, but this isn't the exact same use case:

[Push Twilio alerts to Slack Channel directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391889/push-twilio-alerts-to-slack-channel-directly)

Wasn't sure if there was a native solution within Twilio to send these alerts, either via email or JSON webhook, or if we need to program a function within Twilio to send these events.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Twilio Alarm to notify you via email, in the console, or webhook.
In Twilio Under Monitor > Alarms you can create a new alarm.

[image]

Set your error code to: `30034 - US A2P 10DLC - Message from an Unregistered Number`

Set up your thresholds and choose your notification method.

Using a no-code method you could pass the webhook to Zapier, and then have Zapier make the post in the Slack Channel.  Or there are any dozen other of ways to do this.  But that could tide you over until you get your 10DLC campaign approval.